# Broadcom wireless adapter problems

Tags: wireless, software-installation, broadcom

I have a Broadcom wireless card, 14e4:4365 rev 01. The system doesn't recognize my adapter. I went through the troubleshooter and tried to install bcmwl-kernel-source, but the terminal stalled at the end trying to write a file. I tried to install again and it said I needed to remove first. I tried to remove and the terminal stalled again. Is there someone who can walk me through what I should be doing? Otherwise the install is working fine.

Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

I'm brand new to Linux and deeply appreciate any help.

Here's the history from the terminal, shows where it got hung up at the end

```
susan@Purple:~$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for susan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
Kernel:  4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-20-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-20-generic
```

Comment: Is the behavior improved if you do: `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade` followed by: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.  I also tried firmware-b43-installer.  I see contradictory suggestions for 14e4:4365 and I'm not always sure which card ppl are talking about.  I think I should do a fresh install to start from scratch.  The question is what to try after the fresh install?

Comment: I'm thinking install firmware-b43-installer first and then bcmwl-kernel-source second.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is helpful:susan@Purple:~$ sudo modprobe wl
[sudo] password for susan: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic
susan@Purple:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: Now I've done a fresh install. This time I checked the box to include proprietary drivers and the bcmwl-kernel-source was added to the install. The Additional Drivers tab of Software and Updates says it is in use. My Broadcom 14e4:4365 is still not recognized.  An ethernet connection and a USB wireless card both work. Everything else seems to work fine except Bluetooth which doesn't find devices. "A: Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers" doesn't seem relevent anymore. What should I try next? I'd like this to have wifi without a dongle. Thanks

Comment: Solved! I read @Pilot6 suggestion in another comment to disable secure boot and that did the trick.  Do I need to leave secure boot disabled?  All is well.

Comment: Yes, secure boot should remain disabled. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255